# Is there a way to force a particular line in my Dockerfile to always rebuild, whilst still benefiting from caching on the preceding layers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I frequently seem to have to write Dockerfiles like this (line numbers added for clarity):

```
1. FROM somebase
2. RUN cp /some/local/stuff /some/docker/container/path
3. RUN some-other-local-commands
4. RUN wget http://some.remote.server/some.remote.path.for.example.json
5. RUN some-other-local-commands-which-may-depend-on-the-json
```

On line (4), I'm fetching a remote resource. Let's assume for now that's a JSON file. It might change from time-to-time, maybe not on every build, but perhaps every few hours or days.

What this means is that every time I build my container, I want to ensure the freshest JSON file is fetched. One way to force this is to add the `--no-cache` parameter to my `docker build` command, but this forces all of the lines/layers to rebuild, including (1)-(3), where that is likely not necessary. Is there a pattern or technique to automatically 'taint' or 'mark' line (4) so that Docker knows it always has to re-run the `wget` (presumably this would also have to force a rebuild of line 5), whilst still getting the layer caching behaviour for lines (1)-(3) when Docker detects the pre-req files haven't changed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it's a dupe. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the specific thing you're trying to trigger rebuilds is the result of `RUN wget ...` a specific URL, Docker does actually have native support for this.

There are two similar commands to copy files into a container.  `COPY` only copies files from the build context.  [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) can also fetch external URLs and unpack local archives (but not both at the same time).  The general recommendation is to use `COPY`, unless you need one of the specific things `ADD` does differently.

So you should be able to say

```
ADD http://some.remote.server/some.remote.path.for.example.json .
RUN some-other-local-commands-which-may-depend-on-the-json
```

and the `RUN` command will use the Docker layer cache based on the contents of the fetched file.

If this approach doesn't work for you (maybe you need special authentication to fetch the file) you can also fetch the file outside of Docker before you run `docker build`, and then `COPY` it in.  Again, it will work like any other file you `COPY` in, and layer caching will take effect based on whether the file has changed or not.

Comment: David, thanks for your answer. I think this is "wrong", though, for two specific reasons. Firstly, you're right, in the case of `wget` then ADD will fetch a remote file, but my use of `wget` was only intended to indicate an example of an external network action. Could be a `curl` POST for example, or something completely different. Secondly, your answer is the opposite of what (hopefully!) I was asking for. I want `ADD` *not* to use the layer cache, not to use it. Otherwise, `RUN wget` will do the same job.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies, I re-read your answer. I understand it now. `ADD` would do the job in my case, yes. But I am looking for a more generic answer for network-based RUN lines (or even non-network-based).

Comment: For the specific case of fetching an external file by URL, you can use `ADD`.  There's not a more general solution, though; the question @jonrsharpe links to describes a similar `ADD`-based workaround for `git clone`, but there's not a way to tell Docker "always try to `RUN` this specific step, but maybe go back to the cache if nothing is changed".

Comment: The linked answer has some hacks that are acceptable to me (e.g. the line which calls random.org) but appreciate that's a hack. Thanks anyway for your input. I'll mark your answer as correct because it does answer the narrow interpretation of my question.

Comment: This will never work for git clone ...

Comment: That's true.  For a variety of reasons, some related to layer caching, I generally recommend running `git clone` outside of Docker.